# Shopify - Add Number (1,2,3) before Product in Collection

Tags: loops, for-loop, shopify, liquid, nested-for-loop

I want the collection page to look like a numbered list (1. product 2. product 3. product ...) with a number in front of each product title.

In the **product-grid-item.liquid** I found the title and added **{{ forloop.index }}** in front of it but nothing shows up. When I add **{% for product in collection.products %}{% endfor %}** around it, it shows "123456789 title". When I add {% for product in collection.products %} before the top div and {% endfor %} after the bottom div, it repeats the whole collection multiple times.

When I use **{% cycle '1', '2', '3', '4', '5' %}** it shows "1." in front of every product.

What am I doing wrong? Are there other ways? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not much cleared, but actually want to do?

Comment: Need to much clearer description along with visual examples if any?

Comment: Something like this https://prnt.sc/kscq7eqgYjvO

Comment: [![SCR-20221011-ktz.jpg](https://i.postimg.cc/1XcC3vgQ/SCR-20221011-ktz.jpg)](https://postimg.cc/64qLHLLj)

Comment: @Onkar Yes exactly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so this bellow code is for default Dawn theme from Shopify.
You need to edit the `main-collection-product-grid.liquid` and then navigate to code `render 'card-product'` and pass the `foorloop.index` as `counter`
[image]

on file `card-product.liquid` use it before the title
[image]

Need to add some logic to calculate correct number, add this code to calulcate it
[image]

```
{%- if paginate.pages > 1 -%}
   {% assign page_size =  paginate.page_size %}
   {% if paginate.current_page > 1 %}
     {% assign currPage = paginate.current_page | minus: 1 %}
     {% assign loop_item = page_size | times: currPage %}
     {% assign loop_item = loop_item | plus: forloop.index %}
   {% else %}
     {% assign loop_item = forloop.index %}
   {% endif %}
{% else %}
  {% assign loop_item = forloop.index %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Great advice, it's working fine now, the only problem is that on page 2 the counter starts again at number 1. How can I improve it so that it continues to count on page 2?

Comment: update the answer, you can check it on here also https://liquid-codes-demo.myshopify.com/collections/all

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you have PP? buymeacoffee doesn't work for me..

Comment: use the same email from the profile, happy to help you